# OpenLayers custom VectorSource based on protobufs?

Tags: openlayers, point, layers

I've been having some difficulty finding the answer to this, but is it possible to have custom VectorSources for a WebGLPointsLayer in OpenLayers? I have a gRPC stream that my React client is receiving, and I want to be able to display this data on the map without having to convert them into GeoJSON or one of the other supported formats. The loaders don't seem to be the right place to accomplish what I'm looking for. Is this possible, or do I have to do the unwanted conversions?

Comment: See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-points-layer.html.

Comment: I've seen that @TomazicM but it doesn't answer the question. That's a GeoJSON format example and has no information on how to do make it work with a custom format...unless there's something I'm completely overlooking.

Comment: And what format is your custom source? You can always use custom loader to deal with it.

Comment: @TomazicM - It comes in as a protobuf object and then I was (hoping) to store the object in a dictionary. I'll look more into the custom loader - it wasn't the obvious answer from what I had read, but maybe I misinterpreted something.

Comment: So you'll have to decode protobuf data in custom loader. See `loader` option in vector layer source: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html

Comment: The thing that has thrown me off in that is it's such a specific example using an XHR loader. I'll play around with it and see if I can get it to work.